# body background image not spanning entire height

Tags: html, css

I have this css for my body tag

```
background: url(images/homepagebg.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

But it stops short at the bottom of the page. The image is high enough to fill my whole screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add fixed to the end of the background property, eg

```
  background: url(images/homepagebg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML body only covers your entire screen if the entire screen is used up by content.

you can try

```
 body{
    min-height: {height-of-your-image-in-pixels}px;
 }
```

Comment: This isn't true, I tried creating a wrapper inside the body tags that has height and width at 100%, and it ends up covering the content area, however my body tag covers more height but still stops short of the bottom of the page. The body tag background should cover the whole screen. As for your suggestion, I can't do that, I have the image centered so it gets cropped at the users screen/browser height, and so setting a height would ruin this.